# settings not opening in ubuntu 20.04 (CCS disabled)

Tags: gnome, software-center, settings, system-settings

I'm a new user of Ubuntu 20.04, whenever i try to open settings, i receive the message '"Settings" is not responding.'

when I use `gnome-control-center` on terminal, I get this message:

```
../src/intel/isl/isl.c:2105: FINISHME: ../src/intel/isl/isl.c:isl_surf_supports_ccs: 
CCS for 3D textures is disabled, but a workaround is available.
```

I've tried using `sudo apt --reinstall gnome-control-center` but I still have issue opening settings.

(fyi not sure if this is relevant but while installing ubuntu i ran into issues with the graphics, so i followed this guide: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/727490/how-can-i-use-ubuntu-22-04-on-a-samsung-galaxy-book-2-np750xed and changed some settings.)